# Can't insert linebreaks and ampersands in math mode using \newif

Tags: beamer, formatting, conditionals

I write lecture notes and beamer slides using lots of macros containing math expressions.    I'd like to be able to format conditional on whether or not I'm running beamer.   So I've written conditional code using a `\newif` statement, which works *except* when I want to include formatting characters like `\\` and `&`, in which case beamer throws an error.  Here's sample code:    There are three `\ifThenBeamer` lines of code:  the first two throw the same error, i.e.,

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.40 \end{frame}
```

The third line is fine.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newif\ifConditionOnBeamer
\makeatletter
\def\isConditionOnBeamer#1{
        \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\useBeamer}{#1}=0
                \ConditionOnBeamertrue
        \else
                \ConditionOnBeamerfalse
        \fi
}
\makeatother
\def\useBeamer{on}
\def\BeamerOn{\isConditionOnBeamer{on}}
\def\BeamerOff{\isConditionOnBeamer{off}}
\def\ifThenBeamer#1#2{
    \ifConditionOnBeamer
        {#1}
    \else
        {#2}
    \fi
}
\BeamerOn
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
\ifThenBeamer{a \\ b}{c   d} %This throws a Missing } inserted error
\ifThenBeamer{a & b}{c   d}%This throws a Missing } inserted error
\ifThenBeamer{a b}{c   d}
\end{align}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Could somebody please explain why the error is being thrown, and how to fix it?   Or else a workaround if it's unfixable?

Thanks!

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you expect the output to look like, but if you split the code into two separate `align` blocks (the first appropriate for the "on" and the second for the "off" condition), and put these into the two branches of `\ifThenBeamer`, that should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environment `align` internally uses a table (`\halign`) and macro `\ifThenBeamer` puts group braces around it arguments. The groups messes with the groups of the table cells and lines. Without the braces the example works:

```
\def\ifThenBeamer#1#2{
    \ifConditionOnBeamer
        #1%
    \else
        #2%
    \fi
}
```

A more defensive version moves the expansion of the conditionals at the beginning:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ifThenBeamer}{%
  \ifConditionOnBeamer
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

First `\ifConditionOnBeamer` is called. Then the `\expandafter` in the branch executes the closing `\else` or `\fi. It remains`\@firstoftwo`or`\@secondoftwo`. The macro reads the two arguments and selects one of them. Then`#1`or`#2` are called without a following token from the conditional.

Comment: Sorry @DavidCarlisle, don't understand?    can't find any mail anywhere???

Comment: Thanks @heiko-oberdiek, your first suggestion works, but the second throws the error, `You can't use \spacefactor in math mode`

Comment: @LeoSimon See: [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/16967)

Comment: @LeoSimon that was for Heiko, sorry.

Comment: Thanks very much @heiko-oberdiek,  works now.   Seems odd to me that we had to switch to `\newcommand*` from `\def`, which *doesn't* work, even when enclosed in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.    But "if it ain't broke..."